# Notice: Array to string conversion in ... Warning: copy() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in

Tags: php, mysql

Hola que tal estoy realizando un sistema para cargar archivos PDF de manera simultanea, pero me muestra estos mensajes:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sgrh\modulos\gestion_planillas\cargaboletas.php on line 166

Warning: copy() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sgrh\modulos\gestion_planillas\cargaboletas.php on line 192

he encontrado ejemplos y estado unificando los codigos y sinceramente no doy con la solucion del problema. por favor me puede ayudar?, le presento el codigo:

```
<?php

                    //////////////////////// PRESIONAR EL BOTÓN //////////////////////////
                    if(isset($_POST['insertar'])){
                        $items2 = ($_POST['id_servidor']);  
                        $items3 = ($_POST['codigo_sap']);
                        $items4 = ($_POST['servidor']);
                        $items5 = ($_FILES['archivo']['name']);
                        $tamano = ($_FILES['archivo']['size']);
                        $ruta = ($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']);
                        $destino = "boletas/".$items5;
                        $items6 = ($_POST['motivo_nomina']);
                        $items7 = ($_POST['proceso_planilla_mes']);
                        $items8 = ($_POST['proceso_planilla_anio']);
                        $items9 = ($_POST['fecha']);
                        $items10 = ($_POST['hora']);
                        $items11 = ($_POST['responsable']);
                        $items12 = ($_POST['estado']);
                        $items13 = ($_POST['id_dependencia']);
                        ///////////// SEPARAR VALORES DE ARRAYS, EN ESTE CASO SON 4 ARRAYS UNO POR CADA INPUT (ID, NOMBRE, CARRERA Y GRUPO////////////////////)
                        while(true) {
                        //// RECUPERAR LOS VALORES DE LOS ARREGLOS ////////
                        $item2 = current($items2);
                        $item3 = current($items3);
                        $item4 = current($items4);
                        $item5 = current($items5);
                        $item6 = current($items6);
                        $item7 = current($items7);
                        $item8 = current($items8);
                        $item9 = current($items9);
                        $item10 = current($items10);
                        $item11 = current($items11);
                        $item12 = current($items12);
                        $item13 = current($items13);
                        ////// ASIGNARLOS A VARIABLES /////////////////// 
                         if ($items5 !="" && !empty($_POST['id_servidor'])) {
                          if (copy($ruta, $destino)) {
                              $id_servidor=(( $item2 !== false) ? $item2 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $codigo_sap=(( $item3 !== false) ? $item3 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $servidor=(( $item4 !== false) ? $item4 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $archivo=(( $item5 !== false) ? $item5 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $motivo_nomina=(( $item6 !== false) ? $item6 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $proceso_planilla_mes=(( $item7 !== false) ? $item7 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $proceso_planilla_anio=(( $item8 !== false) ? $item8 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $fecha=(( $item9 !== false) ? $item9 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $hora=(( $item10 !== false) ? $item10 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $responsable=(( $item11 !== false) ? $item11 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $estado=(( $item12 !== false) ? $item12 : ", &nbsp;");
                              $id_dependencia=(( $item13 !== false) ? $item13 : ", &nbsp;");
                              //// CONCATENAR LOS VALORES EN ORDEN PARA SU FUTURA INSERCIÓN ////////
                              $valores='("'.$id_servidor.'","'.$codigo_sap.'","'.$servidor.'","'.$archivo.'","'.$motivo_nomina.'","'.$proceso_planilla_mes.'","'.$proceso_planilla_anio.'","'.$fecha.'","'.$hora.'","'.$responsable.'","'.$estado.'","'.$id_dependencia.'"),';
                                //////// YA QUE TERMINA CON COMA CADA FILA, SE RESTA CON LA FUNCIÓN SUBSTR EN LA ULTIMA FILA /////////////////////
                                $valoresQ= substr($valores, 0, -1);
                                $sql = "INSERT INTO asignar_boletas_original (id_servidor, codigo_sap, servidor, archivo, motivo_nomina, proceso_planilla_mes, proceso_planilla_anio, fecha, hora, responsable, estado, id_dependencia) 
                                VALUES $valoresQ";

                              $sqlRes=$conexion->query($sql) or mysql_error();  
                                // Up! Next Value
                                $item2 = next( $items2 );
                                $item3 = next( $items3 );
                                $item4 = next( $items4 );
                                $item5 = next( $items5 );
                                $item6 = next( $items6 );
                                $item7 = next( $items7 );
                                $item8 = next( $items8 );
                                $item9 = next( $items9 );
                                $item10 = next( $items10 );
                                $item11 = next( $items11 );
                                $item12 = next( $items12 );
                                $item13 = next( $items13 );
                                // Check terminator
                                if($item2 === false && $item3 === false && $item4 === false && $item5 === false && $item6 === false && $item7 === false && $item8 === false && $item9 === false && $item10 === false && $item11 === false && $item12 === false && $item13 === false) break;   
                                      } 
                                   }   
                    }
                          
                        echo mensajes('Boleta(s) Registrado con Exito','verde');
                    }

                  ?>
```

tambien les adjunto el diseño del formulario con una tabla:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">                      
                             <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                       <div class="input-group-addon">
                                              <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Seleccionar la Nomina
                                       </div>
                                       <select class="form-control selectpicker" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                              <option value="" selected disabled>--Seleccionar--</option>
                                              <option value="BOLETA DE HABERES">BOLETA DE HABERES</option>
                                              <option value="BOLETA DE GRATIFICION">BOLETA DE GRATIFICION</option>
                                              <option value="BOLETA DE CTS">BOLETA DE CTS</option>
                                              <option value="BOLETA DE UNIFORME">BOLETA DE UNIFORME</option>
                                              <option value="BOLETA DE ESCOLARIDAD">BOLETA DE ESCOLARIDAD</option>
                                              <option value="BOLETA ADICIONAL">BOLETA ADICIONAL</option>
                                        </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">                      
                             <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                       <div class="input-group-addon">
                                              <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Seleccionar el Mes de Proceso de Planilla
                                       </div>
                                       <select class="form-control selectpickere" style="width: 100%;" required>
                                            <option value="" selected disabled>--Seleccionar--</option>
                                            <option value="ENERO">ENERO</option>
                                            <option value="FEBRERO">FEBRERO</option>
                                            <option value="MARZO">MARZO</option>
                                            <option value="ABRIL">ABRIL</option>
                                            <option value="MAYO">MAYO</option>
                                            <option value="JUNIO">JUNIO</option>
                                            <option value="JULIO">JULIO</option>
                                            <option value="AGOSTO">AGOSTO</option>
                                            <option value="SETIEMBRE">SETIEMBRE</option>
                                            <option value="OCTUBRE">OCTUBRE</option>
                                            <option value="NOVIEMBRE">NOVIEMBRE</option>
                                            <option value="DICIEMBRE">DICIEMBRE</option>
                                        </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="bootstrap-timepicker">                      
                             <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                       <div class="input-group-addon">
                                              <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Seleccionar el Año de Proceso de Planilla
                                       </div>
                                       <select class="form-control selectpickeres" style="width: 100%;" required>            
                                                <option value="" selected disabled>--Seleccionar--</option>
                                                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                                                <option value="2025">2025</option>
                                       </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                    <table class="table bg-info"  id="tabla">   

                      <thead>
                        <tr align="center">
                          <th width="30%">ID_SERVIDOR</th>
                          <th width="0%" class="visible-md">CODIGO SAP</th>
                          <th width="0%" class="visible-md">SERVIDOR(A)</th>
                          <th width="36%">ARCHIVO</th>
                          <th width="15%">MOTIVO NOMINA</th>
                          <th width="11%">PROCESO DE</th>
                          <th width="8%">PLANILLA</th>
                          <th width="0%" class="visible-md">FECHA</th>
                          <th width="0%" class="visible-md">HORA</th>
                          <th width="0%" class="visible-md">RESPONSABLE</th>
                          <th width="0%" class="visible-md">ESTADO</th>
                          <th width="0%" class="visible-md">ID_DEPEN</th>                                       
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <tr class="fila-fija">
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="id_servidor[]" required>
                                   <option value="" selected disabled>---Selecione---</option>
                                           <?php
                                                $sal=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maestrapersonal WHERE id_dependencia='$id_dependencia'");       
                                                while($col=mysql_fetch_array($sal)){
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$col['id'].'">'.$col['nombre'].'</option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                            </select> 
                        </td>
                        <td class="visible-md">
                          <input name="codigo_sap[]" class="form-control" readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="visible-md">
                            <input name="servidor[]" class="form-control" placeholder="SERVIDOR" autocomplete="off" readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="archivo[]" class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input required name="motivo_nomina[]" id="nomina" class="form-control" placeholder="NOMINA" autocomplete="off" readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input required name="proceso_planilla_mes[]" id="procesoplanillames" class="form-control" placeholder="MES DE PROCESO" autocomplete="off" readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input required name="proceso_planilla_anio[]" id="procesoplanillaanio" class="form-control" placeholder="AÑO DE PROCESO" autocomplete="off" readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="visible-md"><input name="fecha[]" class="form-control" <?php echo 'value="'.$fecha.'"';?> readonly/></td>
                        <td class="visible-md"><input name="hora[]" class="form-control" <?php echo 'value="'.$hora.'"';?> readonly/></td>
                        <td class="visible-md"><input name="responsable[]" class="form-control" <?php echo 'value="'.$nombres.'"';?> readonly/></td>
                        <td class="visible-md"><input name="estado[]" value="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Estado"/></td>
                        <td class="visible-md"><input name="id_dependencia[]" class="form-control" <?php echo 'value="'.$id_dependencia.'"';?> readonly /></td>
                        <td class="eliminar">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                
                  </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div class="btn-der">
                      <button type="submit" name="insertar" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> GUARDAR</button> 
                      <button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Estos son los Script para cargar los select a las cajas de texto.

```
<script>
    $(".selectpicker").on("change", function(){
        $('#nomina').val($(".selectpicker option:selected").text());
    });
 </script>
 <script>
    $(".selectpickere").on("change", function(){
        $('#procesoplanillames').val($(".selectpickere option:selected").text());
    });
 </script>
 <script>
    $(".selectpickeres").on("change", function(){
        $('#procesoplanillaanio').val($(".selectpickeres option:selected").text());
    });
 </script>
```

Y este Script es para agregar mas filas en la tabla va dentro del HEAD

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
      
        $(function(){
        // Clona la fila oculta que tiene los campos base, y la agrega al final de la tabla
        $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
          $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone().removeClass('fila-fija').appendTo("#tabla");
        });
       
        // Evento que selecciona la fila y la elimina 
        $(document).on("click",".eliminar",function(){
          var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
          $(parent).remove();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Revisa las dos variables que le pasas a `copy`, dice que alguna de ellas es un array. Pon un `var_dum($ruta);` y un `var_dump($destino);` y verifica las salidas.

Comment: Creo que el error viene del input donde mandas el archivo, estas declarando el nombre como un arreglo name="archivo[]", entonces $_FILES['archivo']['name'] ya no lo puedes llamar directamente sin un indice, puedes probar dejando solo name="archivo" ? Si necesitas enviar multiples archivos, tambien tendrias que ajustar tu codigo y hacer un loop en el array que se envia

Comment: Estimado AugusoM, realice lo que me comentaste, ahora el formulario me guarda 2 registros en la base de datos pero no almacena el nombre del archivo, luego verifico en la carpeta que almacena los pdf y veo que solo guardó un archivo que es el segundo y sale este mensaje Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sgrh\modulos\gestion_planillas\cargaboletas.php on line 181 y este mensaje Warning: next() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sgrh\modulos\gestion_planillas\cargaboletas.php on line 217